# How to get TypeScript files add in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I've created a blank project in Visual Studio 2015 and then added an existing project web application. Next, I created a new folder namely as `TS`and then from `Add New File` prompt I am trying to add `.ts` file. But I am unable to see TypeScript file type.

Below are my visual studio and TypeScript details:

`Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015`

`Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3`

`Microsoft .NET Framework`

`Version 4.7.02556`

`TypeScript   2.8.3.0`

`TypeScript tools for Visual Studio`

I've below solutions but nothing is working on my side.

1. Add new file as `js` and then rename it to `.ts` or `.d.ts`
2. remove cache from `AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have installed TypeScript? You can use `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Yes TypeScript is already installed globally and the version is 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
Go to settings, type in *file associations* and then click on *Edit in settings.json*. There, add the following:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.ts": "typescript"
}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, couldn't get this, Go to Settings. Do you want me in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, this is in VSCode settings.

Comment: got it setting.json. do you want me to copy whole script and paste there?

Comment: No, the image is just to illustrate how to add the snippet of code. You only have to add the part that I described above. Just the `files associations` part.

Comment: Added in VS code. But my problem was with VS 2015, where I am not able to create/add typescript file

Comment: From your question you are implying that you can't see the file you created as a TS file. " But I am unable to see TypeScript file type.". So you create the file, but you don't see it?

Comment: Here is the complete sentence from question: I created a new folder namely as TS and then from Add New File prompt I am trying to add .ts file

Comment: I created folder with name as TS and then I tried to add typescript file from Add New File prompt of VS 2015